# Calling cython generated .c from c using visual c++

Tags: python, c, cython

I have been trying to follow the examples outlined in http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html for using cython declarations from c, Specifically this: "You can make C types, variables and functions defined in a Cython module accessible to C code that is linked with the module, by declaring them with the public keyword:"

integrate.pyx:

```
cdef public double f(double x):
    return x**2-x

cdef public double integrate_f(double a, double b, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double s, dx
    s = 0
    dx = (b-a)/N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a+i*dx)
    return s * dx

def g(a, b, N):
    return integrate_f(a, b, N)
```

After building the .c, .pyd, .h, .obj, .lib, .exp with `python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc` i am able to successfully import and run `integrate.g()` from python.  However, my new goal is to call `f(double x)` and `integrate_f(double a, double b, int N)` from the Developer Command Prompt For VS2015.

Following instructions from the link above, I create a integrate_main.c file:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "integrate.h"
#include <stdio.h>

double f() {
    Py_Initialize();
    initintegrate();
    double x = 3;
    Py_Finalize();
    return f(x);
}

double main()
{
printf("%d", f());
return f();
}
```

Now integrate_main.c, integrate.c, integrate.pyd, integrate.h, integrate.obj, integrate.lib, integrate.exp sit in the same directory.  I try to compile integrate_main.c with `cl integrate_main.c` But get the following syntax errors:

```
...\integrate.h(15): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'f'
...\integrate.h(15): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
...\integrate.h(15): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
...\integrate.h(16): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'integrate_f'
...\integrate.h(16): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
...\integrate.h(16): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
```

I don't understand how there are syntax errors from the integrate.c when cython was successfully able to create a .obj and a importable .pyd.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! And: do not use a C++ compiler to compile C code.

Comment: I am aware that c is not c++...Please see link for examples on compiling .c from developer command prompt .... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb384838.aspx

Comment: So why adding C++ tag for a C question then?

Comment: Let me know when you are ready to provide an answer thats useful...

Comment: 1) It _is_ relevant. You should know if adding a language tag. 2) There is a tag for msvc++ actually; no need to add the language tag. 3) Great attitude you have! Did you even look at the code in `integrate.h`?

Comment: No, I have not attempted to sift through the autogenerated integrate.c and integrate.h files.  Is that necessary even though cython is working correctly and i am able to import the .pyd and use g()?   Is there anything obviously wrong with the approach that I've described?